# In how many episodes did the Doctor wear a fez?

Tags: doctor-who

In how many episodes did the 11th Doctor wear a fez?

That seems to be the thing he is most known for, but I only remember him wearing a fez in **one** episode!

Comment: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fez

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen 5 times?

Comment: How is it what he's *most* known for? He's most known for the bow-tie, surely: "Fezzes are cool" was a rip on "Bow-ties are cool".

Comment: @DanielRoseman lol that may be :-P

Comment: I only want to shout "scarf!"

Comment: @DanielRoseman because Fezes *are cool*.

Comment: @Pureferret [the doctor _is_ cool](http://thedoctoriscool.com/)

Answer (score 11):

By my count, three:

- *The Big Bang* (Season 5, episode 13) - The first appearance of the fez, where it gets obtained and worn.
- *A Christmas Carol* (Season 5 Christmas episode) - The fez-wearing Doctor makes a cameo in one of the Christmases spent with Abigail.
- *The Impossible Astronaut* (Season 6, episode 1) - The Doctor wears a fez in his Laurel and Hardy appearance.
- *Kerblam!* (Series 11, episode 7) - Space Amazon sends the Doctor a fez she probably ordered back in his/her 11th incarnation.

It's possible that I'm missing some but they're the ones I've confirmed myself.

Comment: There's also in the 50th Anniversary one, where they're throwing fezzes through time windows or whatever they're called. I forgot whether or not 11 wore it, but 10 definitely did.

Comment: He did.  Clara asks if he'll ever just walk by a fez without putting it on, and he tells her 'never going to happen'.  That implies it happens at least relatively frequently.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a 13th Doctor episode in which she also wore a Fez.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but if anyone else from 2014 stumbles on it, it's worth noting that the fez plays a noteworthy (and really fun) role in Day of the Doctor. I can't speak to the rest of the episodes in season 7, but I don't remember another one.

Comment: Although this is a partial answer (e.g. mentioning an instance where the doctor wears a fez), it would have probably been better to have posted this as a comment...